# Are all simple left modules over a simple left artinian ring isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I've a basic question.

> $R$ is a simple left artinian ring. I want to show that all simple left $R$-modules are isomorphic.

A simple $R$-module $M$ is isomorphic to $R/J$ where $J$ is a maximal left ideal of $R$. Does this imply that $M\cong Ra$ for some $a\in R$, $a\neq 0$?

Many thanks.

Comment: It certainly does imply that $M \cong Ra$ as $R/J$ is generated by $\bar{1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: if $S$ is a simple left module, $S$ is isomorphic to $R/M$ for a maximal left ideal $M$. Then $R\cong M\oplus S'$ for some left ideal $S'$ since $R$ is semisimple, and $S\cong S'$. So it suffices to look only at minimal left ideals. (Incidentally, $S'$ has to be of the form $Re$ for an idempotent $e$, but we won't need that.)

Since $R$ is simple, it's prime, and so if $S$ and $T$ are nonisomorphic minimal left ideals, $ST\neq\{0\}$. But then $St=T$ for some $t\in T$, which provides an isomorphism of S with T : right multiplication by t.

Comment: what are S and S'?

Comment: @Topoguy I added words to help you out. Cheers

Comment: Thanks!!!!!! That's great.

Comment: "since $R$ is semisimple" why is $R$ semisimple? Isn't it simple?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt yes, it is a simple and semisimple ring. Not all simple rings are semisimple, just the artinian ones.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was getting confused with the definitions and thought that a simple ring was one that, when viewed as a module over itself, has no proper submodules (meaning that it couldn't be the direct sum of simple modules as well). However, a simple ring is a ring that has no proper ideals, so it can be semisimple as well.

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt Right. A ring with only trivial right ideals is a division ring, and that is indeed semisimple, but it's much stronger than saying "only trivial *ideals*. A simple ring *might not* be semisimple. It's not hard to find rings R for which R/M isn't Artinian for a maximal ideal $M$, and this is an example of a nonsemisimple simple ring.