# If $R$ is a simple Artinian ring, then when is a finitely generated module free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, self-learning, ideals

Here's an exercise from my book, which only gives a brief solution which leaves me very confused.

> Let $R$ be a simple Artinian ring, say $R=K_r$. Show that there is only one simple right $R$-module up to isomorphism, $S$ say, and that every finitely generated right $R$-module $M$ is a direct sum of copies of $S$. If $M\cong S^k$ say, show that $k$ is uniquely determined by $M$. What is the condition on $k$ for $M$ to be free?

$K_r$ denotes the $r\times r$ matrices over the field $K$ (I imagine).

Book's solution:

> Each row is a simple right ideal and all are isomorphic. $S^k$ is free iff $r\mid k$.

$R$ being a simple Artinian ring means it has no proper submodules, and it has an ascending chain of ideals which eventually breaks off. An ideal is also a $R-$submodule, so if we take the minimal ideal in a chain of the Artinian ring then it can be viewed as a simple $R$-module. A finitely generated module has a generating set (kind of like a basis, but without the condition of linear independence).

Is my answer to the first question on the right track? How do I answer the other three questions?

Why should the $r\mid k$ imply that $S^k$ has a basis?

Comment: The book's suggested answer is totally insufficient. The first question has been asked many times before: here's one solution http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1011301/29335

Comment: *it has an ascending chain of ideals which eventually breaks off.*  Although nothing about this is false, you should hear these two comments: a) the Artinian condition talks about *descending* chains of submodules; and b) *every* descending chain terminates, not just one. (A right Artinian ring is also right Noetherian, so every ascending chain of right ideals terminates as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my answer to the first question on the right track? (Show that there is only one simple right R−module up to isomorphism)

You made a comment about a chain and a minimal ideal, but this isn't going anywhere. The question has been asked a few times before, and you can find an explanation here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1011301/29335

> How do I answer the other three questions?

My advice would be to go read a bit about semisimple rings in a book like Isaac's *Algebra: a graduate course* or Jacobson's *Basic Algebra II* or Lam's *First course in noncommutative rings*. All of these questions are special cases of the theory of semisimple rings.

> Every finitely generated right $R$−module $M$ is a direct sum of copies of $S$

*Every* (not just the finitely generated ones) $R$ module has to be a direct sum of copies of $S$. But the finitely generated ones are the ones that look like $S^k$ for a natural number $k$. I can't think of a better way to prove this than to learn that $R$ is a semisimple ring, and that the modules of semisimple rings are direct sums of simple submodules. If there is only one simple module up to isomorphism (as is the case for a simple semisimple ring) then naturally any module is a direct sum of copies of that module ($S$, in our case.) You'll be able to find this in any of the references I gave before. It's not hard, but it doesn't fit into a post either.

> show that $k$ is uniquely determined by $M$

If $M\cong S^k\cong S^j$, then the endomorphism rings $End(S^k_R)\cong End(S^j_R)$ as rings. But also you can say that $End(S^n_R)\cong M_n(End(S_R))$. Now $End(S_R)$ is a division ring by Schur's lemma, and unless $k=j$, the two matrix rings have different dimension over that division ring. (There are many details to be filled in here: take your time.)

> What is the condition on $k$ for $M$ to be free? (Why should the $r∣k$ imply that $S^k$ has a basis?)

Thinking in terms of bases is not nearly as big of a win as thinking of free modules as "sums of copies of $R$." Now, $R$ is certainly a finitely generated $R$ module, so $R\cong S^k$ for some $k$. Every finitely generated free module is a finite direct sum of copies of $R$. So... how many copies of $S$ does such a module have?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. "how many copies of S does such a module have?" Each copy of $R$ is of dimension $r$, and each one is isomorphic to $S^k$ for some $k$...so the number of copies will be some multiple of $r$?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt Yes. And conversely, any time you see part of a  module that looks like $S^k$, you can just replace it with $R$, because they're isomorphic as modules.