# Is the ring $R$ a free module over $S$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, free-modules

> $S$ is a simple Artinian ring with unity. $S \subset R$ is a ring extension.
> I know an additional condition that $R$ is finitely generated as left or right $S$-module. Is it true that $R$ is free as an $S$-module?

I know that S has only one simple module V. And $R \cong V^{(n)}$ as S-modules. R must be a finite direct sum of V by decomposing its unit 1. Then I don't know how to prove R is free over S. I heard that it is about a lemma of Artin and Whaples. But I can't find this lemma.

Comment: Are your rings commutative?

Comment: Noncommutative rings with unit 1.

Comment: $R$ need not be a _finite_ direct sum of $V$.  The infinite product of rings $S^{\mathbb{Z}}$ has infinite rank over $S$.

Comment: In the finite-dimensional case, this follows from Artin-Wedderburn; see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361063/if-r-is-a-simple-artinian-ring-then-when-is-a-finitely-generated-module-free).

Comment: Thanks, I add the condition that R is finitely generated as S-modules. But I can only apply  Artin-Wedderburn theorem to S. I still can not see that R is free over S.

Comment: From the answer to the linked post: "I can't think of a better way to prove this than to learn that $S$ is a semisimple ring, and that the modules of semisimple rings are direct sums of simple submodules. If there is only one simple module up to isomorphism (as is the case for a simple semisimple ring) then naturally any module is a direct sum of copies of that module ($V$, in our case.) You'll be able to find this in any of the references I gave before. It's not hard, but it doesn't fit into a post either."  (I changed the names of variables to match your notation.)

Answer (score 1):

I find Artin-Whaples' lemma. It's recorded in "Structure of rings" by Jacobson.
Here's the script of the proof. There is a general propostion for idempotents : $e_1 R \cong e_2 R$ if and only if $\exists e_{12}, e_{21}\in R$,

$e_1 e_{12} e_2 = e_{12}, e_2 e_{21} e_1= e_{21}$

$e_{12}e_{21} = e_1, e_{21}e_{12} = e_2$.

In our case, $S = \oplus I_i$ as a direct sum of minimal right ideals. Decompose the unit as $1 = e_1 + ... + e_k, e_i\in I_i$. And construct right ideals $e_i R$ in R.
Applying this proposition, we can find $e_{i,j},e_{j,i}\in S$ in our case. And thus, $e_iR$ are isomorphic as R-modules. Of course they are isomorphic S-modules.

Since $e_i$ are orthogonal idempotents, $R= \oplus e_iR$. We don't have to assume R is finitely generated as S-module at the beginning. The real field over the rational is a good example of infinitely generated module.

Comment: The timing of this is really funny.  I felt sure there had to be a counterexample in the infinite-rank case.  Then I found [an abstract proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4391406/330413) that handles all possible ranks.  I check back here, and you scooped me by 10 minutes!  Nicely done — I like this argument.  :)