# Can a matrix ring have a non-free ring extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, free-modules

Let $D$ be a skew field, and consider an arbitrary noncommutative unital ring $R$ extending the matrix ring $D^{n\times n}$.  Must $R$ be free as a $D^{n\times n}$-module?

If $R$ is finite-dimensional, then $R$ is indeed free, as I pointed out in the comments to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4391325/is-the-ring-r-a-free-module-over-s) (which inspired this one).  Likewise if $n=1$, by undergraduate linear algebra.  But is the same true for infinite-dimensional rings when $n\geq2$?

Now, [$\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ is not free over $\mathbb{Z}$](http://reh.math.uni-duesseldorf.de/%7Eschroeer/publications_pdf/infinite_product-1.pdf).  So the simplest example I can think of is the infinite direct product $(\mathbb{C}^{2\times 2})^{\mathbb{Z}}$ over $\mathbb{C}^{2\times 2}$.  But I can't tell if even such a simple example is free.

Comment: Obviously, my verb tense in the last sentence became wrong once I figured out the answer posted below, but (1) I still don't know how to show that example by calculation, as opposed to generalities and (2) I don't want this question to get deleted for lack of context.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would expect that there is a concrete way of proving it. I mean, forget about the non-commutative case, how would you show "by calculation" that $\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is free over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @CaptainLama: Fair enough.  I find the Zorn's lemma/transfinite induction argument is pretty concrete, but I see how one could think otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, the answer is "yes, all such rings are free."  (Your proposed counterexample is not one.)

To see this, first note that $D$ and $D^{n\times n}$ are Morita-equivalent (Corollaries 4.5 and 5.5 of [these notes](https://pages.uoregon.edu/anderson/rings/COMPLETENOTES.PDF)).  Since $D$-vector spaces are projective (they're free!), every $D^{n\times n}$-module must be projective too.  But then Corollary 3.2 of [Hyman Bass, "Big Projective Modules are Free"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.455.5945&rep=rep1&type=pdf) proves that any infinitely-generated projective module over a simple Noetherian ring (such as $D^{n\times n}$) is free.

I do not know any elementary argument to prove this result.

Comment: Using Bass's result is overkill. The fact that every infinitely generated module over a simple artinian ring $D^{n\times n}$ is free is much more elementary. You can prove this using the Morita equivalence. $D$ has a unique simple module (the one-dimensional $D$-vector space) and every $D$-module is a direct sum of copies of the simple module (every vector space has a basis). So the same is true of $D^{n\times n}$ ...

Comment: ... For $D^{n\times n}$ the free module of rank one is a direct sum of $n$ copies of the simple module. So any direct sum of any multiple of $n$ copies of the simple module (including the direct sum of any infinite set of copies) is a free module.